# Loading an unmanaged DLL using LoadLibrary in an ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, f#, loadlibrary

I'm working on an ASP.NET web site, developing in Visual Studio 2010.  Most of the site is written in managed code (F# and C#), but it uses an unmanaged DLL (QuickPDF) for some of its functionality.  The site works fine running locally, but when deployed to a hosting provider (aspnethosting.co.uk), the LoadLibrary call fails, returning a handle of IntPtr.Zero.

According to the hosting provider's console, the site is running at a trust level of Full (Internal).

The DLL is in the web site's bin directory and the hosting provider tells me that it has appropriate permissions.

I've tried using no specific path at all to the DLL, using .\, and also working out what the current assembly path is using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase (see F# code below) - which works fine when running locally.

Anything else I can do to help pin this down?

Here's the F# code which works out the path to the DLL:

```
let assemblyDirectory =
    let codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    let uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase)
    let path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path)
    Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
```

Here's where the F# code uses that path (having checked it points to the DLL)

```
let dllPath = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "QuickPDFDLL0814.dll")
if not (File.Exists(dllPath)) then
    failwith ("Could not find QuickPDF DLL at: " + dllPath)
let lib = QuickPDFDLL0814.PDFLibrary(dllPath)
```

Here's the C# code where an attempt is made to load the QuickPDF dll - this is where it fails - ie. dllHandle IS equal to IntPtr.Zero.

```
    public PDFLibrary(string dllFileName)
    {
        dll = new DLL(dllFileName);
        if (dll.dllHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            instanceID = dll.QuickPDFCreateLibrary();
            dll.RegisterForShutdown(instanceID);
        }
        else
        {
            dll = null;
        }
    }
...
    public DLL(string dllFileName)
    {
        dllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllFileName);
        if (dllHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not load library " + dllFileName);
        else
        {
```

Comment: see what's Marshal.GetLastWin32Error returns after the LoadLibrary call

Comment: Antonio - Thanks for the hint.  It returns 0.  Not sure what that is telling me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I cracked it.  QuickPDF supply a 32bit and a 64bit version of the DLL.  I needed to be using the 64 bit version.  [Red face.]  Thanks to those who supplied answers.

Answer (score 1):

LoadLibrary fails when dll can be loaded.

It may happen when the DLL does not exist (not found) OR the DLL exists (and found) but some dependences of this DLL could not be loaded.
I suggest you:
1. compare PATH environmental variable for both cases. Try GetEnvironmentVariable function.
2. Find out what components are used by QuickPDF.dll and verify if they are presented at aspnethosting.co.uk